# Combining formatting with functional changes

Tags: git, refactoring

You are normally asked to make some feature. But, when making the functional changes, you notice a lot of poor coding in other places. It happens always, as your coding skills improve. You want to fix them right away. It is desirable to clean up the code right away because it is terribly annoying and you know that you will forget about it when finished with the feature. You also want to hardens your coding best practices, applying them where you see appropriate. You will be too lazy to look for something that is not an eyesore. But, you want to set aside all the non-feature concerns and you won't come back to rewise the code until the next feature is requested, which means that there is no place to fix the poor coding. It is easiest as you go but a pain at later time.

I would like to spawn all unrelated small formatting changes and collect them into a separate commit as I am busy with functional coding. What are the best practices for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always do separate refactor commit. If you spot some bad code, reformat it before before you start your feature. It will help to track what you have done to finish task and what you did as a refactoring part in later code review.

If refactor is very close to things you are implementing, refactor it right away. If there are not touching your work directly, consider other git branch for those changes or at least another commit.

To do separate commits you can use `git add --patch` and group your changes by refactor/feature implementation/etc.

Comment: Do you mean that the least hassle is I first fix the coding on-the-fly, as I do my feature and, later, filter the changes splitting them into two commits with `patch` option?

Comment: @LittleAlien yes, that is one option but it won't work everytime. It works only if your reformat/refactor is away of your current work on some feature

Comment: That is exactly what I need! Because the changes that mess with my feature are fixed as part of the feature. It is valid to think that they are because I need to rewrite that piece of code for my feature anyway and we can legitimately pretend that it was fine -- I just needed to update it for my feature. So, my question concerned only distant, absolutely unrelated pieces of code. And I need it only because everybody needs this option :)